# JavaScript support of Lookaheads and Lookbehinds in Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

Does JavaScript support positive and/or negative lookaheads/lookbehinds?  Which combinations of them?  Or, to be more specific:

1. Positive lookaheads
2. Negative lookaheads
3. Positive lookbehinds
4. Negative lookbehinds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript has support for only positive and negative lookahead with **no support** whatsoever for lookbehinds, but you can still mimic the latter in Javascript using callbacks.

There is a nice article about this **[here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript)**, actually although this article uses callbacks to provide some sort of an alternative support for lookbehind, the same principle can be used in other languages that support lookbehinds but not variable expressions in them so it is handy trick.

Answer (score 7):

Here in 2020 some browsers do also support lookbehind (lookahead has been supported from the beginning):

- **IE** no support
- **Edge** 79+
- **Firefox** 78+ (very fresh)
- **Chrome** 62+
- **Safari** no support
- **Opera** 49+

Source: https://caniuse.com/#search=Lookbehind

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't support any lookbehind, but it can support lookaheads.

So:

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. No
4. No

You can find more details about the specifics of JavaScript regex on [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).